# What's this art made of LED's or screens called?

Tags: style-identification

I'm looking for the name of art that is made from LED's or screens, not in in real life but drawn or with 3D programs. I really like this style of art and don't know the name of it.

E.G:

https://gyazo.com/f2586f38699e97a46b1baec08cafe491

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIoDx2OjQK4

Comment: This is (basically) "pointillism," regardless of whether it is CGI or real-life. Some might argue that it is a more modern concept and point to pop art etc. but Lichtenstein (for example) used Ben Day dots which is a system that predates pointillism.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not particularly sure that there is a name for this style of art. The only thing I was able to find was something called LED art, which is a form of light art. I managed to find some info on it by accessing Google. Be sure to check out [Enviral Design](http://www.enviral-design.com/) and a few other sites I found on Google. I hope that this puts you in the right direction.....good luck!